# Getting the path of the required folder and its content

Tags: java

I am trying to get the paths of all the contents of a given folder, say I have a folder structure something like this:

The path to this folder is: `c:\\path\\to\\folder\\docs\\`

```
docs
|
+- someFolder (c:\\path\\to\\folder\\docs\\someFolder\\)
|   +- someText.txt (c:\\path\\to\\folder\\docs\\someFolder\\someText.txt)
+- movie.mp4 (c:\\path\\to\\folder\\docs\\movie.mp4)
```

What I am trying to do is that:

to get the path names as

`["docs\", "docs\someFolder\someText.txt", "docs\movie.mp4"]` AKA relative paths. I am using `Commons IO` to list out all the files and folders in a given path as:

```
List<String[]> paths = new ArrayList<>();


File f = new File(folderPath);

for (File k : FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs(f, TrueFileFilter.TRUE, TrueFileFilter.TRUE)) {
    paths.add(k.getPath().split(Pattern.quote(File.separator)));
 }
```

One way is to split the main `folderPath` and get its last index - where ever the `docs` is present (that's what I did in the above code). Then iterate over the `paths` array and slice it from `0` to the index where ever `docs` is avliable.

I tried doing `Arrays.asList(k.getPath().split(Pattern.quote(File.separator))).subList(0,6).clear()` but I don't know how to put this in a ist or an array.

Is there any alternative to this?

**Update**

The reason why I need an alternative is that, I can't add `Arrays.asList(k.getPath().split(Pattern.quote(File.separator))).subList(0,6).clear()` to an array list as `clear` returns nothing. Also I just don't know how to add `Arrays.asList(k.getPath().split(Pattern.quote(File.separator)))` to a list of `List<String[]> paths = new ArrayList<>()` if I do this I get an error as:

```
Error:(162, 18) java: no suitable method found for add(java.util.List<java.lang.String>)
    method java.util.Collection.add(java.lang.String[]) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that java.util.List<T> conforms to java.lang.String[])
    method java.util.List.add(java.lang.String[]) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that java.util.List<T> conforms to java.lang.String[])
```

I have no idea what that means, but if I change `List<String[]> paths = new ArrayList<>()` to `List<Object> paths = new ArrayList<>()` it works and again there is a problem with `Object`. It's confusing.

Comment: why do you need alternative

Comment: @Sundeep added the reason.

Comment: To be honest i am a bit confused, all you want is to get all the content of a folder ( files and folders ) and store the absolute path of each one of them into a list right?

Comment: yes!! @JKostikiadis did I over explain it?

Comment: @akshay not really, its just 6:22 am and i am still half asleep. In any case my recommendation is to not over thinking about it and try to keep it simple as possible. Big fan of the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the way I would do it is by a recursive method like the one below, I have commends inside the code to explain the process :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        // arguments are your folder and the list you
        // want to add the results
        collectFiles(new File("C:/"), list);

        for (String s : list) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    private static void collectFiles(File folder, ArrayList<String> list) {
        // Add the current file/folder to the list
        list.add(folder.getAbsolutePath());

        // If its not a directory return cause we already add it
        if (!folder.isDirectory())
            return;

        // We found a directory so get all the files in it
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        // In case the above returns null return
        if (listOfFiles == null)
            return;

        // For every file in the list
        for (File f : listOfFiles) {
            // if its a directory do a recursive call 
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                collectFiles(f, list);
            } else {
                // we found a file so add it to the list
                list.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }
```

**Edit :**

Well asking for relative paths could be done easily just by manipulating the strings in the list, but this would be the naive approach. The best solution I can think of is to use one more parameter which will hold the relative path:

```
private static void collectFiles(File folder, String relativePath, ArrayList<String> list) {
        // Add the current file/folder to the list
        list.add(relativePath);

        // If its not a directory return cause we already add it
        if (!folder.isDirectory())
            return;

        // We found a directory so get all the files in it
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        // In case the above returns null return
        if (listOfFiles == null)
            return;

        // For every file in the list
        for (File f : listOfFiles) {
            // if its a directory do a recursive call
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                collectFiles(f, relativePath + File.separator + f.getName(), list);
            } else {
                // we found a file so add it to the list
                list.add(relativePath + File.separator + f.getName());
            }
        }
    }
```

And you just call it like :

```
File searchFolder = new File("C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop");
collectFiles(searchFolder, searchFolder.getName(), list);

for (String s : list) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Edit 2 : Well you ask the method to return the List instead so below there is that version as well :

```
private static ArrayList<String> collectFiles(File folder, String relativePath) {

        ArrayList<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        resultList.add(relativePath);

        if (!folder.isDirectory())
            return resultList;

        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        if (listOfFiles == null) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }

        for (File f : listOfFiles) {
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                ArrayList<String> currentResults = collectFiles(f, relativePath + File.separator + f.getName());
                resultList.addAll(currentResults);
            } else {
                resultList.add(relativePath + File.separator + f.getName());
            }
        }

        return resultList;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but this is giving an absolute path, would it be possible to get a relative path something like `["docs\", "docs\someFolder\someText.txt", "docs\movie.mp4"]` without the `c:\...`

Comment: Sure you can 'cut' the name of absolute path depending on what you mean by "relative" path, for example if you are searching on the folder C:/users/X/Desktop/ then we want all the results to be from Desktop/... and so on and just discard the C:/users/X right?

Comment: Exactly. I am not sure how to do that

Comment: @Akshay Check the above edit and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: @Akshay Hmm why you want to make the recursive method to return a List? this will cause a lot of overhead believe me but its possible I guess.

Comment: The end product for using this would be to get the list of paths and give to Azure Storage SDK that can upload all the files and create folders accordingly based on the relative paths - basically they act as the name of the file and place it will be stored at. but this works to, I would just write a loop to do the uploading anyway.

Comment: @Akshay Well I made a second edit and show it just for reference just to know how it could be done.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your requirement right, you can just use string replace to do the job for you.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.TrueFileFilter;

public class DirectoryListing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String folderPath = "c:\\path\\to\\folder\\docs\\";
        String parentDirectory = "docs";
        System.out.println(findFilePaths(folderPath, parentDirectory));
    }

    public static List<String> findFilePaths(String folderPath, String parentDirectory){
        List<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
        File f = new File(folderPath);
        for (File k : FileUtils.listFiles(f, TrueFileFilter.TRUE, TrueFileFilter.TRUE)) {           
            paths.add(k.getPath().replace(folderPath, parentDirectory));
         }
        return paths;
    }

}
```

My test directory tree:
[image]

with this run parameters:
`String folderPath = "C:\\00docs";`
`String parentDirectory = "docs";`

result list is coming as:
`[docs\00\File00.txt, docs\00\File00A.txt, docs\00docs\File00DocsA.txt, docs\01\File01.txt, docs\File00DocsP.txt]`

Comment: ~but would this work if the path is something like `c:\\path\\docs\\to\\folder\\docs\\`?~ yep this works

Comment: Yes it should, all you are doing is getting the absolute path from `k.path()` & replacing the path upto parentDirectory path with directory name to make it relative. You can test run it. It works like charm at my end.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use NIO this can be much simpler.

```
public List<Path> findFilesAsRelativePaths(Path directory) throws IOException {
    try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.find(directory, Integer.MAX_VALUE, (path, attrs) -> attrs.isRegularFile())) {
        return stream.map(directory::relativize).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

This uses [`java.nio.file.Files.find(Path, int, BiPredicate, FileVisitOption...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#find(java.nio.file.Path,int,java.util.function.BiPredicate,java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...))

If you need the paths as `String`s you can simply call `Path.toString()`. Or if you need them as a `File` you can convert it with `Path.toFile()`.

Also, if you want directories as well you can change `(path, attrs) -> attrs.isRegularFile()` to `(path, attrs) -> true`. Although it may just be better to use [`Files.walk(Path, int, FileVisitOption...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk(java.nio.file.Path,int,java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...)).

Answer (score 1):

To get a path relative to other path import use `relativize` of java [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/nio/file/Path.html):

```
//import java.nio.file.Path;
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> paths = getPaths("c:\\path\\to\\folder\\docs\\", "c:\\path\\to\\folder");
    paths.forEach(p ->  System.out.println(p));
}

private static List<String> getPaths(String sourcePath, String sourceParentPath) {

    List<String> paths =  new ArrayList<>();
    getPaths(sourcePath, Paths.get(sourceParentPath), paths);
    return paths;
}

private static void getPaths(String sourcePath,Path parent, List<String> paths) {

    paths.add(parent.relativize(Paths.get(sourcePath)).toString());

    File file = new File(sourcePath);

    if( ! file.isDirectory()) {//if directory, search it
        return;
    }

    if(file.list() == null) {//for abstract path or errors
        return;
    }

    for (String fileName: file.list() ){

        getPaths((sourcePath+"\\"+fileName), parent, paths);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input